# Sorting a multi-dimensional JSON object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, flickr

I tried finding an answer to this on here, but kept coming up with real simplistic examples, so here goes:

I am pulling a photoset list from Flickr's API, and it needs to be in javascript. Anyhow, their response is unlike most others places the value to sort within a sub-object like so:

```
"photoset":[
    {..."photos":"15", "videos":0, "title":{"_content":"Shocktoberfest 2012"}, "description":{"_content":""}, "needs_interstitial":0, "visibility_can_see_set":1, "count_views":"0", "count_comments":"0", "can_comment":0, "date_create":"1351829136", "date_update":"1351829309"}
    ...
    ...
    ...
]
```

How can I sort on the title for instance, when the value is within in a sub-object like it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could provide a callback to the [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and return the usual -1, 0, 1 for sorting:

```
some_response.photoset.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return a.title._content.localeCompare(b.title._content); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure either but , I would begin to figure it out with a for/in statement loop...

```
var photoObjects= {};
for(k in initialObject){
    photoObjects[k] = initalObject.photoset[0][k];
    console.log(photoObjecs[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows you to pass a function as parameter to the Arrays sort function,

you could just write a simple helper function to sort an array with object after there titles

```
var arr = [
  {title:"A"},
  {title:"F"},
  {title:"B"}
];



function sortarr (arr,item) {
  arr.sort(function (a,b) {
    if (typeof a == "object" && typeof b == "object" ) {
      console.log(a[item]);
      if ( a[item] < b[item] )
        return -1;
      if ( a[item] > b[item] )
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }
  });
return arr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortarr(arr,"title")));
```

Here is an example on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aqeluc/1/edit)